# How can I get more details about "error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.PLAYBACK/104"

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to cast an m3u8 from one server and I get `error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.PLAYBACK/104` after the first segment but when I download the segments and the m3u8 manifest and put it on my local server it all works just fine. I can play the video from the server that gives the error on other players.

I've already checked CORS headers, I've used curl to pull the segments myself and they work just fine.

So how can I get more details about what leads to this error?

> error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.PLAYBACK/104

EDIT: Log with debug enabled.

`[ 78.475s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"requestId\":6,\"type\":\"LOAD\",\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"http://domain/file.m3u8",\"streamType\":\"BUFFERED\",\"contentType\":\"application\\/vnd.apple.mpegurl\",\"metadata\":{\"metadataType\":1,\"images\":[{\"url\":\"thumbnail",\"width\":100,\"height\":100}],\"title\":\"title",\"subtitle\":\"subtitle\"},\"duration\":null,\"tracks\":[]},\"autoplay\":true,\"currentTime\":0}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"senderid"}
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 78.479s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 78.485s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 78.492s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager load event
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 78.509s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load message received:{"requestId":6,"media":{"contentId":"http://domain/file.m3u8","streamType":"BUFFERED","contentType":"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl","metadata":{"metadataType":1,"images":[{"url":"thumbnail","width":100,"height":100}],"title":"title ","subtitle":"subtitle"},"duration":null,"tracks":[]},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":0}
player.js:2063 onLoad_
player.js:2063 Cancelled deferred playback: new media is loaded
player.js:2063 onLoad_
player.js:2063 Loading: video
player.js:2063 resetMediaElement_
player.js:2063 setType_: video
player.js:2063 loadVideo_
player.js:2063 letPlayerHandleAutoPlay_: true
player.js:2063 loadVideo_: using Media Player Library
player.js:2063 Regular video load
media_player.js:25  [ 78.374s] [cast.player.api.Player] Version: 1.0.0.37
media_player.js:25  [ 78.385s] [cast.player.api.Player] load
media_player.js:25  [ 78.397s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://domain/file.m3u8 -1]
media_player.js:25  [ 78.410s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://domain/file.m3u8 -1]
media_player.js:25  [ 78.418s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://domain/file.m3u8 -1]
media_player.js:25  [ 78.441s] [cast.player.core.MediaSourceManager] open
player.js:2063 loadMetadata_
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 78.666s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
player.js:2063 customizedStatusCallback_: playerState=IDLE, this.state_=loading
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 78.677s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":5,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"IDLE\",\"currentTime\":0,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false},\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"http://domain/file.m3u8\",\"streamType\":\"BUFFERED\",\"contentType\":\"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl\",\"metadata\":{\"metadataType\":1,\"images\":[{\"url\":\"thumbnail\",\"width\":100,\"height\":100}],\"title\":\"title \",\"subtitle\":\"subtitle\"},\"duration\":null,\"tracks\":[]},\"currentItemId\":5,\"idleReason\":\"ERROR\",\"extendedStatus\":{\"playerState\":\"LOADING\",\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"http://domain/file.m3u8\",\"streamType\":\"BUFFERED\",\"contentType\":\"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl\",\"metadata\":{\"metadataType\":1,\"images\":[{\"url\":\"thumbnail",\"width\":100,\"height\":100}],\"title\":\"title \",\"subtitle\":\"subtitle\"},\"duration\":null,\"tracks\":[]}},\"repeatMode\":\"REPEAT_OFF\"}],\"requestId\":0}"}
media_player.js:25  [ 78.521s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://domain/file.m3u8 200]
media_player.js:25  [ 78.631s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: initial 0
media_player.js:25  [ 78.643s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: http://domain/file.m3u8
media_player.js:25  [ 78.662s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://domain/file.m3u8 -1]
media_player.js:25  [ 78.671s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://domain/file.m3u8 -1]
media_player.js:25  [ 78.679s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://domain/file.m3u8 -1]
media_player.js:25  [ 78.747s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://domain/file.m3u8 200]
player.js:2063 preloaded=false
media_player.js:25  [ 78.893s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: seek success Infinity
media_player.js:25  [ 78.910s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://domain/seg1.ts -1]
media_player.js:25  [ 78.918s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 10000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://domain/seg1.ts -1]
media_player.js:25  [ 78.925s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://domain/seg1.ts -1]
media_player.js:25  [ 78.977s] [cast.player.core.MediaSourceManager] sourceopen
media_player.js:25  [ 78.986s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] buffer type: video/mp2t; codecs="avc1.4D401E,mp4a.40.2"
media_player.js:25  [ 79.140s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://domain/seg1.ts 200]
media_player.js:25  [ 79.151s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: current=17976.10, average=643526.48
media_player.js:25  [ 79.158s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: process segment
media_player.js:25  [ 79.165s] [cast.player.hls.Adaptation] process segment
media_player.js:25  [ 79.172s] [cast.player.hls.Adaptation] start: 9596.795999999998
media_player.js:25  [ 79.177s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: segment processed
media_player.js:25  [ 79.224s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: abort
media_player.js:25  [ 79.229s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: timestampOffset = -0.7089999999989232
media_player.js:25  [ 79.232s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append 564 bytes
media_player.js:25  [ 79.247s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
media_player.js:25  [ 79.649s] [cast.player.api.Player] endOfStream 9596.116
player.js:2063 onError
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 79.873s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error: [object Object]pd @ cast_receiver.js:67nd.Xc @ cast_receiver.js:67tb.log @ cast_receiver.js:22G @ cast_receiver.js:23W.Xb @ cast_receiver.js:178g.Xb @ cast_receiver.js:127ec @ cast_receiver.js:30bc @ cast_receiver.js:31(anonymous function) @ cast_receiver.js:29
player.js:2063 onLoadMetadataError_
media_player.js:25  [ 79.675s] [cast.player.api.Player] errorbc @ media_player.js:25$b.Kj @ media_player.js:25Eb.log @ media_player.js:22fc @ media_player.js:26k.xd @ media_player.js:348Fc @ media_player.js:33Bc @ media_player.js:35(anonymous function) @ media_player.js:32
media_player.js:25  [ 79.677s] [cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.PLAYBACK/104bc @ media_player.js:25$b.Kj @ media_player.js:25Eb.log @ media_player.js:22fc @ media_player.js:26dg.S @ media_player.js:112k.xd @ media_player.js:348Fc @ media_player.js:33Bc @ media_player.js:35(anonymous function) @ media_player.js:32
player.js:2063 resetMediaElement_
media_player.js:25  [ 79.691s] [cast.player.api.Player] unload
player.js:2063 onError
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 79.912s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error: [object Object]pd @ cast_receiver.js:67nd.Xc @ cast_receiver.js:67tb.log @ cast_receiver.js:22G @ cast_receiver.js:23W.Xb @ cast_receiver.js:178g.Xb @ cast_receiver.js:127ec @ cast_receiver.js:30bc @ cast_receiver.js:31(anonymous function) @ cast_receiver.js:29loadErrorCallback @ player.js:823dg.S @ media_player.js:112k.xd @ media_player.js:348Fc @ media_player.js:33Bc @ media_player.js:35(anonymous function) @ media_player.js:32
player.js:2063 onLoadMetadataError_
3player.js:2063 discarded obsolete deferred state(idle).
player.js:2063 setState_: state=idle, crossfade=false, delay=undefined
player.js:2063 updateApplicationState_
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.019s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"setappstate\",\"statusText\":\"Ready To Cast\"}"}
player.js:2063 setIdleTimeout_: 300000
player.js:2063 setState_: state=loading, crossfade=false, delay=undefined
player.js:2063 updateApplicationState_
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.060s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"setappstate\",\"statusText\":\"Now Casting: title \"}"}
player.js:2063 setIdleTimeout_: 300000
player.js:2063 Deferring load response, loadedmetadata event not received
player.js:2063 Defering playback for 3000 ms
player.js:2063 setState_: state=idle, crossfade=true, delay=undefined
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.100s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
player.js:2063 customizedStatusCallback_: playerState=IDLE, this.state_=loading
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.106s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":5,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"IDLE\",\"currentTime\":0,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false},\"currentItemId\":5,\"idleReason\":\"ERROR\",\"extendedStatus\":{\"playerState\":\"LOADING\",\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"http://domain/file.m3u8\",\"streamType\":\"BUFFERED\",\"contentType\":\"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl\",\"metadata\":{\"metadataType\":1,\"images\":[{\"url\":\"thumbnail\",\"width\":100,\"height\":100}],\"title\":\"title \",\"subtitle\":\"subtitle\"},\"duration\":null,\"tracks\":[]}}}],\"requestId\":0}"}
player.js:2063 setState_: state=idle, crossfade=true, delay=undefined
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.112s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Nothing to reset, Media is already null
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.115s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to sessionid-40
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.118s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"sessionid-40","data":"{\"requestId\":6,\"type\":\"LOAD_FAILED\"}"}
player.js:2063 setState_: state=idle, crossfade=true, delay=undefined
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.124s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Nothing to reset, Media is already null
player.js:2063 setState_: state=idle, crossfade=true, delay=undefined
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.128s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Nothing to reset, Media is already null
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.131s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Not sending LOAD error as there is no on going LOAD requestpd @ cast_receiver.js:67nd.Xc @ cast_receiver.js:67tb.log @ cast_receiver.js:22G @ cast_receiver.js:23W.gc @ cast_receiver.js:178g.jd @ cast_receiver.js:179(anonymous function) @ player.js:1657(anonymous function) @ player.js:1901listener @ player.js:1996
3player.js:2063 discarded obsolete deferred state(idle).
player.js:2063 setState_: state=idle, crossfade=false, delay=undefined
player.js:2063 updateApplicationState_
cast_receiver.js:67  [ 80.936s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"setappstate\",\"statusText\":\"Ready To Cast\"}"}
player.js:2063 setIdleTimeout_: 300000
player.js:2063 Playing`

Comment: Can you enable logging on your receiver side and collect the console logs there and share the portion that throws the error?

Comment: I've added the log. Thanks.

Comment: Please open a ticket on the Cast SDK issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list) and include the reproduction setup, the log and a stream that exhibits the issue so we can take a closer look.

Comment: Try the suggested solution in this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=1095) by using a `videoElement.setAttribute('src', null);` instead of `videoElement.removeAttribute('src');` in your code. If this solution is not applicable with you, then do the suggested action of Ali Naddaf

Comment: @AliNaddaf I can't include a way to reproduce as the video address expires with time and the one on my own server doesn't have the issue.

Comment: @KENdi I'm not finding that piece of code anywhere, where is it? my receiver is based on the cast reference player.